# Trying to get a flexbox to start lined up in a row, the move different divs up and down when responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to build a footer to a website I'm making, and I need it to be responsive. I've looked into doing a flex-box to match the designs as parts of it move up and others move down when it becomes responsive to screen sizes. But I just cant seem to get it to work.

Here is the designs for both the normal full screen footer and the responsive footer:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I've written so far:

```css
/* Footer SCSS */

.site__ftr {
 background-color: $green;
 width: 100%;
 @include curvededges();
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 2em;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 a {
  text-decoration:none;
 }
 main, div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
}
}
.flex_grid {
 
}

.col {
 flex: 1;
 width: 30%;
}
.col_one {
 flex: 0 0 30%;
}
.col_two {
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.col_three {
 flex: 0 0 30%;
}
@include respond($tablet) {
 .col div {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  }
 .col_one {
  order: -1;
  flex: 2;
  }
 .col_two {
  flex: 5;
  }
 .col_three {
  flex: 1;
  order: -1;
  width: 50%
  }
 .col_four {
  flex: 5;
  order: 2;
 }
}
```

```html
<footer class="site__ftr">
 <div class="flex_grid">
  <div class="col col_one">
   <div class="find_div">
   <h3>How to find us</h3>
    <div class="grey_mail left">
    <?php echo file_get_contents("_assets/core-images/icons/email-grey-01.svg"); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
     <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grey_phone left">
    <?php echo file_get_contents("_assets/core-images/icons/phone-grey-01.svg"); ?>
    </div>
   <div class="number">
    <p id="number" href="tel:"></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col_two">
   <div id="location">
    <div class="map">
            <iframe src="URL"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="mob_ftr">
     <div id="times">
              <h3>Opening Times</h3>
               <div id="days">
               <p>Mon-Fri:</p><p>00:00 - 00:00</p><p>Sat-Sun:</p><p>00:00 - 00:00</p>
              </div>
              <button id="donate" class="btn pink small">Donate now</button>
          </div>
         </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col_three">
   <div class="mailing_list">
    <h3>Join our mailing list</h3>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" name="mailing_list_form" action="" class="contact_form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-100">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-100">
       <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row bottom">
      <div class="col-70">
       <a href="newsletter.php" class="btn_link"><button id="newsletter" class="btn green small left">View previous newsletter</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-30">
       <input type="submit" value="Join" class="btn pink small left" id="mailing_join">
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col_four">
   <div class="follow_us">
   <h3>Follow Us:</h3>
    <a href="">
     <?php echo file_get_contents("_assets/core-images/icons/facebook-01.svg"); ?>
     </a>
     <a href="">
     <?php echo file_get_contents("_assets/core-images/icons/twitter-01.svg"); ?>
     </a>
     <a href="">
     <?php echo file_get_contents("_assets/core-images/icons/instagram-01.svg"); ?>
     </a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for the footer and manipulate the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) property of the items inside a media query.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

footer>div {
  border: thin solid black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .div1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .div2 {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .div3 {
    order: 2;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .div4 {
    width: 100%;
    order: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="div1">How to find us</div>
  <div class="div2">Map</div>
  <div class="div3">Opening times</div>
  <div class="div4">Join our mailing list</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: To complete this solution you could take into account the different position of the donate button and the followus block

Comment: I noticed I had to use five divs in the end to move the follow us block. But this has worked perfectly. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Grid` layout and let the `grid-template-areas` property place all the various modules included in their different position.

> [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJNYjO?editors=0100)

In this example the breakpoint is set to `1000px`. It's worth noting that with this approach you have also a visual representation of the placement of all the blocks inside the style, which make easier to immediately define their right position or to change it.

---

**Markup**

```
<footer>
  <div class="contacts">Contacts</div>
  <div class="openings">Openings</div>
  <div class="followus">Follow us</div>
  <div class="donate">Donate</div>
  <div class="map">Map</div>
  <div class="joinus">Join us</div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.map      { grid-area: map; }
.joinus   { grid-area: joinus; }
.donate   { grid-area: donate; }
.contacts { grid-area: contacts; }
.openings { grid-area: openings; }
.followus { grid-area: followus;  }


/* mobile/tablet style */
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 50px 50px 250px 200px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "contacts openings"
    "contacts followus"
    "donate donate"
    "map map"
    "joinus joinus"
}


/* desktop style */    
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  footer {
    grid-template-rows: 250px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
    "contacts map openings joinus" 
    "contacts map donate followus"
  }
}
```

---

**Final result**

[image]